# OAuth security for calling Controllers using Attrubutes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0

Is there anyway, that you can lets say use OAuth in MVC and enable acces to a controller using Attributes like in validation process.
Lets say i have

```
public class myownController
{ 
  [LoginRequired]
  public ActionResult Index(){
  //this can be accesed only of the user is logged in.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using ASP.Net MVC 4 this should be built in using the default [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).  If not I'd recommend manually integrating the standard Forms Authentication mechanisms with your chosen OAuth provider.  Take a look at [ASP.NET MVC Authentication - Customizing Authentication and Authorization The Right Way](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/05/04/asp-net-mvc-authentication-customizing-authentication-and-authorization-the-right-way.aspx)

Since you are using ASP.Net MVC 4, I'd highly recommend reading [SimpleMembership, Membership Providers, Universal Providers and the new ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC 4 templates](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx).  There are significant changes available in MVC 4 that make the entire Membership and OAuth really easy.

Comment: Updated with specific MVC 4 content.